# Minecraft Modding, hitEntity method not running

Tags: java, overriding, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am fairly new to modding.
I want to create a sword that sets mobs or players on fire. I am using the `hitEntity` method and, I noticed the function is not even running. I tested it using the console. When I use the `@Override` notation before the `hitEntity` method it gives me an error:

> The method hitEntity(ItemStack, EntityLiving, EntityLiving) of type BlazeSword must override or implement a supertype method

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.firstMod.tools;

import com.example.firstMod.FirstMod;

import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLiving;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayerMP;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemSword;
import net.minecraft.potion.Potion;
import net.minecraft.potion.PotionEffect;
import net.minecraft.util.DamageSource;

public class BlazeSword extends ItemSword {

    public BlazeSword(int id, ToolMaterial blaze) {
        super(blaze);
        this.setCreativeTab(FirstMod.blazingMod);
        this.setUnlocalizedName("blazeSword");
        this.setTextureName(FirstMod.MODID+":"+"blaze_sword");
    }

    public boolean hitEntity(ItemStack par1itemstack, EntityLiving par2entityliving, EntityLiving par3entityliving){
        par2entityliving.setFire(20);
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: As you are getting an error with the `@Override` it appears that the `ItemSword` that you are using is the wrong one and does not contain a `hitEntity` method.  I have found one at `net.minecraft.src` that does contain this method.

Comment: Which version of Minecraft Forge?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error you said with @Override, so there is no such method in ItemSword. Look ItemSword class for the right hit method.

Answer (score -1):

The hitEntity method isn't working because you never call it. You declare that it exists but you never run it. What you need to do is call your hitEntity method in your BlazeSword class using your requested variables.
In your BlazeSword class:

```
hitEntity(ItemStack par1itemstack, EntityLiving par2entityliving, EntityLiving par3entityliving)
```

Also, take out @Override since you aren't trying to find the hierarchy of the blaze sword.